# Creating a script that compares multiple files in multiple servers

Tags: perl, shell, ssh, diff, sftp

I have several different linux servers, all of which are essentially mirrors of each other.  However, some of them have gone out of sync (file A in machine 1 is different from file B in machine 2).

I'm in the process of designing a script (`shell` or `Perl` only) that will systematically walk through certain directories and diff the corresponding files in the different machines against each other, and generate a meaningful report.  Later on, I will try to sync up the files.

These are my thoughts so far on how to approach this:

1. sftp files to `/tmp` and diff locally
2. using `ssh` and `diff`
3. using `rsync`

My question is: what is the best way to systematically compare two files that are in different machines (but similar directory structure), and are there any built-in Perl utilities that may be helpful?

Answer (score 2):

rsync will figure out the difference and sync your files by sending only the diff. Once two folders get synced, it will be pretty quick. (But the 1st time to sync will take some time)

Answer (score 1):

You can also use git here. One possible workflow: just checkin all files you want to compare (or complete directories using `git add -A`). Then create an empty git repository on your local workstation which is used fetch all the other repositories, and which is used to do the comparisons:

```
git init
git remote add firstmachine ssh://user@firstmachine/path/to/directory
git remote add othermachine ssh://user@othermachine/path/to/directory
git fetch --all
```

Now the contents of two machines may be compared:

```
git diff remotes/firstmachine/master remotes/othermachine/master
```

Or just compare the contents of a specific file:

```
git diff remotes/firstmachine/master remotes/othermachine/master -- file/to/compare
```

It's not strictly necessary to use a third machine for the comparisons. You can also git-fetch the contents from othermachine to firstmachine.

Answer (score 0):

I had worked on a similar tool (which was in `python`). What it did was, run a `cron` job, at a given time of the night, which would bring the `tar` `bzipped` files to one server, extract the directories and run a recursive `diff` on it. The `diff` output was then run through some `python` scripts, which would analyse the `diff` hunks (`+` lines/`!` lines etc) to know the amount of change.

Not sure if there are pre-built modules in `Perl` or `Python`, but some helper utils might sure be available in one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to know the difference between some local and remote file systems, the following method minimizes the network load:

1. make a local copy ($C) of the local directory ($D) you want to compare. I.e.:

   ```
   cp -R $D $C
   ```
2. use rsync to copy the remote directory ($R) you want to compare over $C:

   ```
   rsync -av --delete $remote_host:$R $C
   ```
3. compare $D to $C:

   ```
   diff -u $D $C
   ```